# View Product name in customer area, right beside order number

Tags: magento-1.8

someone did know a solution: Is it possible, to show the Product name in customer area, right beside order number?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible! If you are using default theme in magento, then need to change the code in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/history.phtml`. If you are using any other theme, look for that file accordingly. If the file is not there in your theme, then you've to make the change in base location, where I mentioned earlier.

---

```
<?php
/**
 * - added class for selected columns
 * - removed width="1" in the last column
 */
?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $_orders = $this->getOrders(); ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Orders') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($_orders->getSize()): ?>
<table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table">
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Order #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Ship To') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Status') ?></span></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="cell-label"><?php echo $this->__('Order #') ?></span><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
            <td><span class="cell-label"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span>
            <?php $orderItems = $_order->getItemsCollection();

            foreach ($orderItems as $item){
                $product_name = $item->getName();
                echo $product_name; }
                ?></td>
            <td><span class="cell-label"><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></span><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
            <td><span class="cell-label"><?php echo $this->__('Ship To') ?></span><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
            <td><span class="cell-label"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
            <td><span class="cell-label"><?php echo $this->__('Order Status') ?></span><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
            <td class="a-center">
                <span class="nobr"><a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                    <?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                    <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-orders-table');</script>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('You have placed no orders.'); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

---

This is the whole code for your requirement, I've added 
`<th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>` 
and

```
<td><span class="cell-label"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span>
            <?php $orderItems = $_order->getItemsCollection();

            foreach ($orderItems as $item){
                $product_name = $item->getName();
                echo $product_name; }
                ?></td>
```